# In Swift if you unwrap a "Implicitly Unwrapped Optional" is this a double unwrap?

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I was investigating the difference between ! and ? in var declaration.

My Question in brief

```
If you call unwrap! on a a var declared with ! - why isnt this a double unwrap?
```

I created two IBOutlets as this is when ! is used a lot

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar1: UISearchBar? //"Optional"
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar2: UISearchBar! //"Implicitly Unwrapped Optional"
```

I understand that if outlets are non nil then all these will work

```
self.searchBar1!.text = "dd" //builds ok but crashes on nil
self.searchBar2!.text = "dd" //builds ok but crashes on nil

self.searchBar1?.text = "dd1" //builds ok but does nothing on nil
self.searchBar2?.text = "dd1" //builds ok but does nothing on nil

//---
self.searchBar1.text = "dd2"  //ERROR: 'UISearchBar?' does not have a member named 'text'
self.searchBar1!.text = "dd2" //OK: must unwrap Optional(UISearchBar) to UISearchBar
self.searchBar1!.text = "dd2" //OK: must unwrap Optional(UISearchBar) to UISearchBar 

self.searchBar2.text = "dd2"  //ok unwrap declared in var but will crash if nil
//----
```

Am I correct in thinking the last line works because the unwrap is in the var declaration

this works because Unwrap! is in var declaration

```
self.searchBar2.text = "dd2"
```

Why doesnt this crash - isnt this a double unwrap

```
self.searchBar2!.text = "dd"
```

self.searchBar is Optional(UISearchBar) >> Unwrap! self.searchBar2! >> UISearchBar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two key sentences in [the book](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_496) are:

> An implicitly unwrapped optional is a normal optional behind the scenes, but can also be used like a nonoptional value, without the need to unwrap the optional value each time it is accessed.

and

> You can think of an implicitly unwrapped optional as giving permission for the optional to be unwrapped automatically whenever it is used.

My understanding here is that an implicitly unwrapped optional is just like a normal optional, and can be accessed like one, including using the unwrapping! operator on it. Implicit unwrapping simply removes the *need* to unwrap, rather than making it an error if you don't.

It's a "normal optional... but *can* *also* be used like a nonoptional value"—to me that implies that both methods of accessing it are fine.

Comment: How is the  Implicitly unwrapped optional! implemented. Compiler magic e.g. ? is changed to Optional<T> or in the swift framework as some operator overloading, which is what I was looking for so was confused as I read it as a double unwrap. myVar!!.

Comment: Yes, as far as I know it's compiler magic interacting with the [ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional](http://swifter.natecook.com/type/ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional/) type.

Answer (score -1):

If variable `var` declared as `Type!`, then any reference to `var` is equivalent to `var!`. You can think that compiler adds `!` every time you use this variable. There's no "double unwrap" here, it's single unwrap.